# Как удалить всё содержимое в папке, но саму папку оставить?

Tags: linux, консоль, archlinux, zsh

Как удалить всё файлы, папки, ссылки в папке, но саму папку оставить?
У меня есть временная папка temp и в неё я кладу файлы, а после работы с ними я хотел бы удалить всё содержимое. У меня есть файлы типо **.zshrc** **temp.txt** и так же папки с дочерними подпапками и скрытыми каталогами типо **.config** и так же есть обычные файлы типо **info.txt** **temp.php** и т.п. А также есть файл в имене которых есть две точки типо **..12**

Как очистить всё это из папки **temp** ??

Я уже пробовал команду `sudo rm -rf /home/temp/.* /home/temp/* /home/temp/*.*`

Но она не всегда срабатывает. Eсли в папке **temp** будет находится все типы перечисленных файлов тогда да, она сработает, но если же например только папка и всё, а остальных типов файлов не будет, то выдает это

```
no matches found: /home/temp/*.*
```

Хотя папка с подпапками существует даже после выполнения команды. 
Если же отдельно вручную удалять по каждой папке и по каждому файлу, тогда всё нормально удаляется. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `find /home/temp -delete`

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev тогда получится что и папка temp удалится, а мне нужно всё её содержимое удалить, а её оставить.

Comment: а, что обязательно в одну команду это делать?

Comment: @PavelGridin если делаешь это каждый день, это начинает утомлять и ищешь пути автоматизации, хоть какой-то...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

например, можно дать указание оболочке (приведены примеры для двух наиболее распространённых программ, выполняющих роль оболочки — *bash* и *zsh*) включать в список подпадающих под шаблон `*` файлов/каталогов **и те**, чьи имена начинаются с точки.

*bash*:

```
$ (shopt -s dotglob; ls -d /путь/*)
$ (GLOBIGNORE=.;     ls -d /путь/*)
```

*zsh*:

```
$ (setopt globdots; ls -d /путь/*)
$ (setopt dotglob;  ls -d /путь/*)
$ (set -o globdots; ls -d /путь/*)
$ (set -o dotglob;  ls -d /путь/*)
```

скобки в примерах используются для того, чтобы переопределение не влияло на текущий процесс оболочки (то, что в скобках, будет выполняться дочерним процессом).

Comment: я немного не понял что нужно сделать с этим? добавить в .zshrc что ли?

Comment: ну скопировал, выполнил и что дальше?? я правда не пойму :(

Comment: если вы о том что после этого все файлы удаляются, то к сожалению нет, это не так

Comment: разумеется. ведь в моём примере приведена программа *ls* а не *rm*.

Comment: Спасибо Вам. Заработало. Как я понял первая команда setopt globdots аналогична трём остальным в zsh? Я использовал её. Этот вопрос конечно выходит за рамки моего основного вопроса, но если Вам не трудно вкратце напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: да, я просто перечислил разные альтернативы.

Answer (score 5):

А по простому:

```
rm -rf ~/tmp
mkdir ~/tmp
```

можно ? :-)

Если "папка не простая, а смонтированная" то будут проблемы. Тогда, что бы избежать фатального действия ощибки

> no matches found:

рекомендую разбить Вашу длинную команду

```
sudo rm -rf /home/temp/.* /home/temp/* /home/temp/*.*
```

на последовательност  элементарных действий:

```
sudo rm -rf /home/temp/.* 
sudo rm -rf /home/temp/* 
sudo rm -rf /home/temp/*.*
```

Тогда отсутствие подходящих файлов в одной команде удаления никак не повлияет на работу остальных команд удаления.